# ListBoxItem style query

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to set the background for my ListboxItem with the help of the ValueConverter. But the background is not applied. On debugging I found that the value converter returns correct  values.
Am I missing something in my code?

**Note: I don't want to use alternate index style**

XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="listBoxItemAlternateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AlternateIndexConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding Path="IsVisible" />
                <Binding Path="Index" />
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Codebehind:

```
 public class AlternateIndexConverter : System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter
{

 public static uint count = 0;

public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool isVisible = bool.Parse(values[0].ToString());
    uint index = uint.Parse(values[1].ToString());

    if (index == 0)
        count = 0;

    if (isVisible && count % 2 == 0)
    {
        count++;
        return "#C8C8C8"; //dark color
    }
    else if (isVisible && count % 2 == 1)
    {
        count++;
        return "#E1E1E1"; //light color
    }
    else
        return null;
}

public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: What errors do you have in your Output Window? I suspect that your problem is that you are returning the `string` representation of `Color` objects instead of new `Brush` objects, which is what the `Background` property takes.

Comment: I dont get any errors. it does work if i use ivalueconverter instead of imultivalueconverter

Comment: I can't really see any other potential problems... did you try returning `Brush` objects instead? Also, have you debugged your `Converter` to check that you are getting the correct values coming into it?

Comment: returning Brush objects work but if i return string from ivalueconverter it works but not imultivalueconverter

Comment: That is very strange... I'm not sure why that happens. I thought that markup extensions (the ability to set a `Brush` property to a string representation of a colour) only worked from markup (XAML). Either way, did that fix your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `Brush` from your `Converter` instead of `String`

```
 if (isVisible && count % 2 == 0)
    {
        count++;
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,200,200,200)); //dark color
    }
    else if (isVisible && count % 2 == 1)
    {
        count++;
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,225,225,225)); //light color
    }
```